# Can string replace be written in list comprehension?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I have a text and a list.

```
text = "Some texts [remove me] that I want to [and remove me] replace"
remove_list = ["[remove me]", "[and remove me]"]
```

I want to replace all elements from list in the string. So, I can do this:

```
for element in remove_list:
    text = text.replace(element, '')
```

I can also use regex.
But can this be done in list comprehension or any single liner?

Comment: A list comprehension is not suitable for this task, because you are not attempting to build a list. Anyone who tells you to use a list comprehension for this is giving you bad advice. If you arbitrarily want it in one line, you could remove the newline in your two-line solution, or use regular expression as you mention in your question.

Comment: Isn't a regex replace a one-liner?

Comment: @khelwood You're correct. But what I was thinking is if I can use list comprehension to get a list of the texts in which each element is cumulative of the updated text, then I can use the last element as the desired output.

Comment: @iBug I can't think of a way to use regex in one line for this. Would be great if you could share the example code. Thanks.

Comment: A list comprehension is not suitable for a cumulative computation where each result depends on the result from the previous iteration. List comprehensions are good for "mapping" and "filtering", not for "folding" or "reducing".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this with `re.sub` to remove all the substrings in one pass:

```py
>>> import re
>>> regex = '|'.join(map(re.escape, remove_list))
>>> re.sub(regex, '', text)
'Some texts  that I want to  replace'
```

Note that the result has two spaces instead of one where each part was removed. If you want each occurrence to leave just one space, you can use a slightly more complicated regex:

```py
>>> re.sub(r'\s*(' + regex + r')', '', text)
'Some texts that I want to replace'
```

There are other ways to write similar regexes; this one will remove the space preceding a match, but you could alternatively remove the space following a match instead. Which behaviour you want will depend on your use-case.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce):

```
from functools import reduce

text = reduce(lambda x, y: x.replace(y, ''), remove_list, text)
# 'Some texts  that I want to  replace'
```

Comment: This is something new for me. I'll have to learn about this. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a regex by building a regex from an alternation of the words to remove, taking care to escape the strings so that the `[` and `]` in them don't get treated as special characters:

```py
import re

text = "Some texts [remove me] that I want to [and remove me] replace"
remove_list = ["[remove me]", "[and remove me]"]

regex = re.compile('|'.join(re.escape(r) for r in remove_list))

text = regex.sub('', text)
print(text)
```

Output:

```
Some texts  that I want to  replace
```

Since this may result in double spaces in the result string, you can remove them with `replace` e.g.

```py
text = regex.sub('', text).replace('  ', ' ')
```

Output:

```
Some texts that I want to replace
```